# On the Force32Bit option of NETLink

Tags: .netlink

It seems that the 32-bit option of `NETLink` has been planed to be ommited since 12.0+. I found that the code

```
  Needs["NETLink`"];
  InstallNET["Force32Bit"->True];
```

become being stuck, because there is no `ml32i4.dll` under the path of `SystemFiles\Links\NETLink` for the file `InstallableNET32.exe`. But if the `ml32i4.dll` copied from the other folder here would be OK. Hope this tip helps.

Comment: It solved the same problem for me. Thank you